# django programming - "create" methods in admin, model or view

Tags: python, django, oop, crud

Baseline: I'm building a django based application that is heavily using the admin interface as it spares me a lot of work in developing own CRUD routines. By now I came across several situations where i have models that hold some general information (say parents) and often have foreignkey-relations to derived models (say childs).

I realized that i sometimes implemented my routines to create child objects within the admin-class, sometimes within the model class(method being called from within some admin routine) or sometimes even within view-classes (e.g.  as reaction to POST requests on some custom forms). It feels now, that my design is not very consistent (the effects of changing some model parameters being distributed over a lot of files) and i should refactor before it gets to big a mess.

So what is the best approach? Where should one concentrate methods that create/modify related objects (keeping in mind that i often want to give some feedback-messages related to process) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If your code is about a `Model` class, add it to `models.py`. This makes sense when the classes have to be added to database (`migrations`)
- If your code is related to `views`, attach it to `views.py`. This makes sense when the code handles requests.
- If your code is related to `admin`, attach it to `admins.py`. This makes sense when the code is related to admin interface.
- If your code is generic, used in multiple places, `refactor` it into a separate file, and `import` that file elsewhere.

Your use case isn't exactly clear to me, so I'm taking a stab in the dark here - You can have the `Models` in `models.py` and create a separate file to create objects for models with child objects containing the code that's related to creating parent-child objects with given data. Then use this as an import in the admin and views wherever applicable.

Something like:

```
# foo in views.py and admin.py
def foo():
    data = {} # get all data
    make_parent_child(data) # create parent-child objects
```

Comment: I will interpret your idea like: Identify and collect within all your actually distributed object creates/updates places the data that actually needs to be processed and put all methods that actually do the work into one (new) file. I tend to directly put them as model class methods but am a little afraid that my model class will include some objects references that the model normally don't know about (like request or admin, which i would need in order to trigger some messages for the user).

Comment: I think that having all methods related to the model in the class itself is fine, as long as there is a definite structure and reason for it, and it doesn't get too messy to handle. If there are too many methods in a class, then you can go for refactoring them into a separate file. IF there's too much repetition in the method, consider abstraction of methods to enable using them for multiple models.